# Get username for SAPUI5 in WebIDE

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

This is probably just some easy JavaScript code i can't figure out, but i am trying to get the username of currently logged in user. Or this is an oData concept, which i am not familiar with. Here is the code for retrieving it:

```
onComment: function (oEvent) 
    {
        //gets username
        var userModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/services/userapi/currentUser");
        var username = userModel;
     console.log(username);
    }
```

I know something is supposed to go after the `var username = userModel` but i cannot get the correct output. Here is what i am getting in the console

**constructor {pSequentialImportCompleted: Promise, mEventRegistry: Object, mMessages: null, id: "id-1501515372158-22", oData: Object…}**

**oData: Object**

**+displayName:"Tyler Genio (Sxxxxxxxx)"**

**+email:"tyler.i.Genio@company.com"**

**+firstName:"Tyler"**

**+lastName:"Genio"**

**+name: "Sxxxxxxxx"**

How do i get the first and last name out of that?
I've see a few articles online that talk about it, but some of it goes over my head.
Sorry for any confusion about the coding format on here.

Comment: Is this app supposed to be used in the Launchpad?

Comment: I believe so. I'm not sure where they are putting this. I am just writing a comment section application. I just need to send the current user to the database

Comment: Hm, do you think that this is UI job to send current user? Can't backend determine that?

Comment: I apologize but i'm really not sure. I kind of got thrown this project and it's been a hell of a learning curve (first time using SAP or HANA or JavaScript). I know that the console is outputting the correct information. I just need to access the oData object from userModel

Comment: Ok, if you are not sure (I suggest to ask backend devs), you can get your properties by "userModel.getProperty("/firstName")" and so on.

Comment: Ok will do. Thank you very much!

Comment: but this is not good approach to get data from backend.. Does your project backend based on odata protocol?

Comment: I dont believe so

Answer (score 1):

if your model is structured as stated, i.e.

```
{
    "displayName": "Tyler Genio (Sxxxxxxxx)",
    "email": "tyler.i.Genio@company.com",
    "firstName": "Tyler",
    "lastName": "Genio",
    "name": "Sxxxxxxxx"
}
```

then userModel.getProperty("/name");

Comment: userModel has several objects shown in the console. "oData" is one of the objects with 5 other objects inside. When i try "userModel.getProperty("/name")" i get _undefined_.

Comment: try to call .getProperty("/") and then you will see the hierarchy.

Comment: or try userModel.oData.name

Comment: I just get a blank _Object{}_
and the other is undefined

Comment: it means that on the next line after initiating your model, the data were not get returned from backend yet, meaning you need to wait until they are received. I think you can use https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#event:requestCompleted callback for that.

Comment: Thanks for y'alls help! Got one problem with it now.
 Running `var username = userModel.getProperty("/name");`
 I get a blank object. when i use `setTimeout ` and have it wait, it works. BUT this does not stop the program and wait for it to finish, so it doesn't get used fast enough. How do i make it wait?